# Python parser for lambda calculus

Tags: python, parsing, lambda-calculus, peg

For fun, I want to write a parser for the untyped Lambda calculus. The
easiest approach is probably write a handwritten parser, but I wonder
if there is a more Pythonic way? Specifically, I want to use a
Python library that translates the syntax description for the language
into a parser. Here is the language's BNF definition:

```
<term> ::= <var>
        |  <term> <term>
        |  λ <var> <term>
```

For simplicity I've omitted paranthesis rules. Application associates
to the left so that `x y z` is `(x y) z`.

What Python library can take the above syntax description, or some
grammar derived from it (as written, the grammar is, I believe, both
ambiguous and left-recursive so it is not trival to implement), and
produce a parser? I want to see how it is done using code, so please
don't just answer "pyparsing can do it". Please write code along the
following lines:

```
>>> G = """syntax description here..."""
>>> parser = build.the_parser(G)
>>> parser.parse("λ x. (y z)")
Abs('x', App(Id('x', Id('y'))))
```

The last line is what the produced abstract syntax tree could be. Abs
stands for abstraction (lambda), App for application and Id for
Identifier. I think a PEG packrat parser generator would work well here.

Answer (score 1):

This ANTLR4 grammar does the trick:

```
grammar T;

program
 : term EOF
 ;

term
 : Lambda Id '.' term
 | '(' term ')'
 | term term
 | Id
 ;

Lambda
 : '\u03BB'
 ;

Id
 : [a-z] [a-zA-Z0-9]*
 ;

Spaces
 : [ \t\r\n] -> skip
 ;
```

Place the above in a file called `T.g4`. Download the [ANTLR4 jar](https://www.antlr.org/download/antlr-4.7.2-complete.jar) into the same folder and do:

```
java -cp antlr-4.7.2-complete.jar org.antlr.v4.Tool -Dlanguage=Python3 T.g4
```

This will create the lexer and parser files.

Now run:

```py
from antlr4 import *
from playground.TLexer import TLexer
from playground.TParser import TParser


tests = [
  'λ x. (y z)', 
  'x y z w'
]

for test in tests:
    lexer = TLexer(InputStream(test))
    parser = TParser(CommonTokenStream(lexer))
    tree = parser.program()
    print("{}".format(tree.toStringTree(recog=parser)))
```

which will print:

```
(program (term λ x . (term ( (term (term y) (term z)) ))) <EOF>)
(program (term (term (term (term x) (term y)) (term z)) (term w)) <EOF>)
```

Comment: Nice! But it won't parse a term like `x y z w`.

Comment: Yes, `x y z w` is a valid term. But you don't have to implement my grammar verbatim. I'm fine with modifications to it as long as it's still readable (defining what I mean by readable is hard of course). ANTLR works too, but is non-optimal as it requires the Java runtime.

Comment: Thank you! I'm hoping for some more lightweight alternatives too.

Comment: Sure, no problem @BjörnLindqvist. Although a lightweight solution that supports left recursive rules are not likely, IMO. I'd be happily surprised if there is such an alternative, of course.

Comment: Why not? The parsing rules for lambda calculus are so trivial so I don't get why a complicated parser is necessary.

Comment: The grammar might not be complicated, but the fact that there are left-recursive productions makes it difficult since most PEGs and LL parser generators do not cope with that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative that removes the left recursion. Although visiting the syntax tree is an exercise for the OP.

```
from parsimonious import Grammar

grammar = Grammar(r"""
    start = term

    term = ('(' _* term1 _* ')') / term1
    term1 = app / atom1

    atom = ('(' _* atom1 _* ')') / atom1
    atom1 = abs / id

    abs = 'λ' _* id _* '.' _* term

    app = atom _+ term

    id = ~"[A-Za-z]+"

    _ = ~"[^\S\n\r]"u
""")

print(grammar.parse("x y z w"))
```

Comment: It is unable to parse `(((x y) z) w)` and `(λx. x x) (λx. x x)` and I also think your application rule is right-associative.